# Using SwiftMailer to send via Gmail suddenly stopped working?

Tags: php, swiftmailer, gmail-imap

For years our website has used the SwiftMailer plugin to send emails via Gmail. However, seemingly randomly yesterday morning it no longer works for us; we get a message

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]'

Any ideas what might have caused this? Did Gmail change something with the settings we need to use? Here's what we have currently:

```
require_once 'path/to/swift-mailer/lib/swift_required.php';
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com')
          ->setPort(465)
          ->setEncryption('ssl')
          ->setUsername('ouremail@gmail.com')
          ->setPassword('ourpassword')
         ;
     $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

The problems started around 11AM yesterday morning, and absolutely nothing was changed on our end around that time. Last week I upgraded our PHP version to 5.6.32, but things were working fine since that upgrade until yesterday morning. I even tried reverting back to the old version (only back to 5.6.30), but the error still persisted. I have researched everything on here and elsewhere on the web I could find on this issue and tried everything I could, including trying TLS, changing the port number, using an IP instead of smtp.gmail.com, but nothing has worked. Any ideas?

EDIT: Just discovered the email still works from my local XAMPP setup. This setup is running PHP 5.5.9. So it must be something with our server or domain name provider.

Comment: Make sure that you have not activated two step varification with the email you are using with SMTP.

Comment: No that has not been activated. IMAP is enabled, and allow access to unsecure apps is turned on.

Comment: __access to unsecure apps is turned on__ is also necessary. It did not work after that change ?

Comment: That has been turned on, and no it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try removing `->setEncryption('ssl')` . Because I read that when you use port 465 it by default uses `ssl`. So give it a try.

Comment: Just tried that, that gave me this error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""'`

Comment: Did you check that the port `465` with your host is open? May be they have some changes and the port is closed after that.!!

Comment: We host our site on our own server. Our domain name provider wouldn't be able to have closed it, would they?

Comment: I have godaddy server and they upgraded my php version to 7.0. it was 5..6 before. So in your case, probably they might have changed something with port too.

Comment: I will have to research this and see if that is the case. I just tested the page in our local XAMPP environment and it works there.

Comment: Oh, so highly recommend checking for port availability with your host. Use this url to check https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: I used this link and sure enough, it says everything but port 80 is closed. Interesting...we've reached out to the person who handles that for us and will see if they can open up the port again.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but 1) its a bit long, 2) the comments section is already full of irrelevance.

So you have code which was known to be working but the intended behaviour changed without a change in the code. And you thought to ask why on a site about code problems?

Something has changed **outside** your code. That's the first place you should be looking.

If gmail had suddenly stopped working or changed its behaviour, I'm fairly sure there would be a lot of people talking about it. Hence the most likely candidate is the infrastucture (including the CAs) supporting your PHP server. But:

1) you've told us nothing about that

2) its off-topic on SO.

Comment: Why, you ask? Desperation and less than 2 hours of sleep last night trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue that the swift mail just suddenly stop working.
The error is

> 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]'

.
I am using laravel with swift mail to send email through gmail box.
The final solution is to download the cert from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
then add "openssl.cafile=path\cacert-2018-01-17.pem" to `php.ini`.
It's because something related to windows ca library is not updated any more.